# Convert a line of Data into a string list

Tags: c#

I have a string which looks like

```
string data = "\"111\",67215,\"JOHN A DOE\",\"123456789\",\"1212\",\"FP3S\""
```

I need to split each of them and store it in database table in their individual column.
I tried to split like

```
string[] separator = new string[]{“,”};
List<string>splitdata = data.split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
```

It will split in 6 columns but give me results like:

```
“\”100|””
“67215”
“\”JOHN A DOE\”” … and so on.
```

I tried again just using double quotes (“”). But it will only split it in 3 columns

```
“\”111\,67215,\”JOHN”
“A”
“DOE\”,\",\"123456789\",\"1212\",\"FP3S\""
```

What I want is like

```
"111","67215","JOHN A DOE","123456789","1212","FP3S"
```

How do I format it so that I get data in above format?

Comment: `List<string> splitdata = data.Split(',').Select(x => $"\"{x.Trim('\"')}\"").ToList();`
Like this? Or like this: `List<string> splitdata = data.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim('\"')).ToList();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ([Demo](https://rextester.com/USN36531)):

```
string data = "\"111\",67215,\"JOHN A DOE\",\"123456789\",\"1212\",\"FP3S\"";
List<string> splitdata = data.Split(',').Select(s => s.Replace("\"", "")).ToList();
```

Comment: Note that this code will remove all `"`, even inside string. `\"JOHN \"A DOE\",` will be `JOHN A DOE`

Comment: Thank you all for your prompt responses. @rad answer best fit my work item. I appreciate all your help. I have been trying to figure out for last 4 hours without any success.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = "\"111\",67215,\"JOHN A DOE\",\"123456789\",\"1212\",\"FP3S\"";
var splittedData = data.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim('\"')).ToList();
```

This code splits string by `,`, and removes `"` from start and end of each string.

Answer (score 0):

Use Replace method to remove \" , After that you could use split to make your collection.

```
string[] items = data.Replace("\"", "").Split(',');
```